# Dynamic rewrite url in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, routes, url-rewriting, nuxt.js

What i want is to have the same behavior as wordpress but with nuxt.

In my page folder i have a structure like below:

```
index.vue
-tools
--_id.vue
--index.vue
-material
--_id.vue
--index.vue
```

My nuxt will generate respective route for these;
So we will take this url example `mydomain.com/tools/1`, in this page i have all content related to tools id 1 that stored in my database; i want to store in my database that this `mydomain.com/tools/1`, is associated to rewrited url `mydomain.com/tools/my-first-tools`; `my-first-tools` here i can update it at anytime but it will always related to `mydomain.com/tools/1`, so in the end when i land in `mydomain.com/tools/my-first-tools`, i want the same content as `mydomain.com/tools/1` and with `mydomain.com/tools/my-second-tools` related to `mydomain.com/tools/2`
The content will dynamicly get by axios using `id` as parameter to get

Is there a way to make it with nuxt?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is [slugs](https://yoast.com/slug/). In your backend you will need to have a way to fetch either by `slug` or `id` but why not do just like Stackoverflow does it?

[This website](https://taskotto.com/blog/14/how-to-achieve-customer-satisfaction-in-5-steps-in-the-hostel-industry) has a combination of the `id` and a `slug` for SEO purposes in its URL. Let's take a look at this URL:

```
https://taskotto.com/blog/14/how-to-achieve-customer-satisfaction-in-5-steps-in-the-hostel-industry
```

Do you see that SO has `blog/{blogId}/{slug}`?! You can do the same in your app:

```
mydomain.com/tools/1/my-first-tools
```

This way you don't need your backend to be able to retrieve either by `slug` or `id`. You will be able to retrieve by `id` only. You will have to re-order your nuxt folder to make sense:

```
tools
-- _index.vue
-- _todoId
--- _slug.vue
```

Comment: sound good idea :) , but if in case  i must use what i asked (i can't use id/slug), is there a way?

Comment: But if you already have `:id` why not just use that? Either I'm not understanding your problem or why I'm not understanding why you can't use the `:id` that you already have to make a request to your backend

Comment: I need the id to retrieve the content from database, but for SEO, i need to rewrite the url to some beautiful url that is updated from backoffice, there is the deal

Comment: @MichelGisenaël You do realize that google will be indexing `mydomain.com/tools/1` and not the newly generated one, right?! That's is why I have suggested the solution above in my answer